# Guardar rutas de archivos en BD Mysql: problema con el caracter de escape '\'

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy intentando guardar la ruta de un archivo en mi BD, pero no se guarda de la manera correcta. Debe ser:

> C:\Users\ro\Documents\relacional.pdf

Al hacer un select en la BD, lo muestra así:

> C:UsersoDocumentselacional.pdf

Obtengo la ruta con el metodo `getPath( )`, y manejo las rutas con una String.

Fragmento de codigo donde saco la ruta:

```
if (selecti.showDialog(null, "abrir") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        archivo = selecti.getSelectedFile();
        if (archivo.canRead()) {
            if (archivo.getName().endsWith("pdf")) {
                String ruta=archivo.getPath();
             rutaacta.setText(ruta);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El archivo seleccionado no es un .PDF");
            }
        }
    }
```

Y así es como lo guardo en la BD con un procedimiento almacenado:

```
  public void guardar() {
    String name = nombre.getText().trim().replaceAll(" +", "");
    String pate = paterno.getText().trim().replaceAll(" +", "");
    String mate = materno.getText().trim().replaceAll(" +", "");
    String dire = direccion.getText().trim().replaceAll(" +", "");
    String phone = telefono.getText().trim();
    String mail = correo.getText().trim().replaceAll(" +", "");
    String depa = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String actan = rutaacta.getText();
    String compro = rutacomprobante.getText();
    String re1 = rutaref1.getText();
    String re2 = rutaref2.getText();
    String stat = status.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String fot = rutafoto.getText();
    String consulta = "call sp_inserta_empleados('" + name + "','" + pate + "','" + mate + "','" + dire + "','" + phone + "','" + mail + "','" + depa + "','" + actan + "','" + compro + "','" + re1 + "','" + re2 + "','" + stat + "','" + fot + "')";
    Conexion = conectar.getconexion();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = Conexion.prepareStatement(consulta);
        int a = ps.executeUpdate();
        sinvacios();
        if (a > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registrado Exitosamente");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al registrar");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegistrarEmpleados.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

¿ Existe alguna manera de que se pueda guardar la ruta correctamente ?

Comment: Y como lo estas guardando?

Comment: con un procedimiento almacenado, he modificado detalles de mi pregunta para ser un poco mas especifico.

Comment: Y en la db esta bien guardada la ruta?

Comment: Tene en cuenta que para un string, el caracter \ se usa como caracter de control, con lo cual es muy probable que tengas que guardar ese caracter de forma doble \\

Comment: en la BD me lo guarda sin \, de esta manera: C:UsersoDocumentselacional.pdf

Comment: Entonces el problema es como lo guadas. y es muy probable que venga por lo que te dije arriba

Comment: \r suele referenciar un retorno de carro en un string

Comment: El problema principal que veo en tu código es que estás usando mal las consultas preparadas. Si usaras los *setter* de que dispone JDBC para insertar los valores, prepared statement se encargaría de escapar lo que haya que escapar, como no lo usas bien, entonces tienes que escaparlo tú a mano, dejando persistir además en el código el grave agujero de seguridad conocido como *Inyección SQL*. Dispones por tanto de una herramienta potente como preparedstatement, pero mal utilizada. ¿Por qué no preparas **realmente** la consulta y seteas los valores aparte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En java y muchos lenguajes, a la hora de trabajar con Strings el símbolo `\` se usa como un carácter de escape (indica al compilador/interprete que el próximo carácter tiene algo de especial y que tiene un comportamiento diferente al habitual).

Por esto para poder utilizar el símbolo `\` tienes que escaparlo (si, escapar el símbolo de escape), siendo el resultado `\\`. Para strings que te den problemas de este tipo, puedes pasarlo por algún formateador online como [este](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html), que te devuelve tu String con estos caracteres escapados.

En conclusión tu string de ruta debería de ser así:

```
C:\\Users\\ro\\Documents\\relacional.pdf
```

Te dejo también un enlace a otra pregunta (en inglés) en la que se trata este [tema](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/112731/what-does-backslash-escape-character-really-escape) de escapar caracteres.